# Does there exist a variant of ARIMA allowing for weighted samples?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, weighted-data, weights

I have a univariate time series exhibiting strong periodicity that I want to forecast, and I plan to use ARIMA. However due to specifics of the prediction task that I'm interested in performing, some of the samples are >100x more important than other samples, and I want to make sure that this information is taken into account when I fit the model.

So, is there any way to incorporate the weighting of samples into an ARIMA model?

Comment: In what way are some observations far more important than others? (1) It is far more important to get them right, or (2) these should have a higher weight in predicting *subsequent* observations? In either case, do you *know* or do you need to *forecast* whether the next observation is important? That said, I don't know of such an ARIMA variant, and I'm not sure one could coherently build it. If (1) above, one could try some kind of "time series [tag:boosting]".

Comment: It is far more important to get them right. The cost function I'm minimizing is a function of sums of non-disjoint subsets of predictions, and therefore the number of sums that a given prediction appears in is directly proportional to its contribution to the cost function.

Comment: I found someone's script that does this by multiplying residuals by some pre-determined weight before computing the error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26849077/2954547